# Why the regex I write doesn't work properly?

Tags: python, regex

```py
pattern = '(ns:m\.[^ ]+ )|(ns:g\.[^ ]+ )'
query = "PREFIX ns: <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/>\nSELECT DISTINCT ?x\nWHERE {\nFILTER (?x != ns:m.0pz91)\nFILTER (!isLiteral(?x) OR lang(?x) = '' OR langMatches(lang(?x), 'en'))\nns:m.0pz91 ns:film.producer.film ?x .\n?x ns:film.film.genre ?c .\n?c ns:film.film_genre.films_in_this_genre ns:g.11b5lzm6b0 . \n}"
entities = re.findall(pattern, query)
```

What I am trying to do is to find all freebase entities in my query, i.e.,`'ns:g.11b5lzm6b0'` and `'ns:m.0pz91'` in my example. However, the code I wrote returns `[('ns:m.0pz91)\nFILTER ', ''), ('ns:m.0pz91 ', ''), ('', 'ns:g.11b5lzm6b0 ')]` instead of `['ns:m.0pz91 ', 'ns:g.11b5lzm6b0 ']`. 
 I solved the problem by using 2 separate regex, i.e., `ns:m\.[^ ]+` and `ns:g\.[^ ]+`, however, I still don't understand why I can't directly use `(ns:m\.[^ ]+ )|(ns:g\.[^ ]+ )` to match `ns:m\.[^ ]+` or `ns:g\.[^ ]+`.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but for starters use raw strings for regular expressions, like `pattern = r'(ns:m\.[^ ]+ )|(ns:g\.[^ ]+ )'`

Comment: @Tomalak Actually, i am not using it with XML. My example is a sparql query.

Comment: @Iguananaut I tried the raw string, it still returns `[('ns:m.0pz91)\nFILTER ', ''), ('ns:m.0pz91 ', ''), ('', 'ns:g.11b5lzm6b0 ')]`

Comment: Also, looking at the string you're trying to match it contains newline characters (`\n`) but you're expecting there to be a space ` `, when there isn't. A space character in a regular expression matches literally one space, so if there isn't a space the regexp won't match. It's not exactly clear to me what you actually want here.

Comment: OK, I didn't think that was it. But regardless you should almost always use raw strings for regular expressions. It would probably help if you provided a larger example of the text you're trying to match against.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex didn't work because of the `\n` and because you are matching anything that is not a `space` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vFCiFt/1)

You can refer to the explanation on the right side of the demo url.

Instead you can try

```
(ns:[mg]\.\w+)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/FszHoV/3)

**Update**

Reason for the presence of tuple in the output of the original regex?

Documentation says:

> this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group

And your regex has two capturing groups.

Comment: Thanks. I see why `'ns:m.0pz91)\nFILTER '` was returned in my original regex, but I still don't know why every element returned by `re.findall` is a tuple with an empty string inside it, i.e., `('', 'ns:g.11b5lzm6b0 ')`

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
\sns:m\.\w*|\sns:g\.\w*
```